# Access desktop files from ADB connected device

Tags: adb, remote-access

Is it possible to access the desktop files from Android device ?

 The device is connected to the desktop through USB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. But, not with ADB. ADB server runs only in Android (Device or Emulator). On PC, you get ADB client only.

With USB, you've got a network. Install a FTP, Samba or SSH **server** (like [FileZilla Server](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server)) on PC & use a FTP, Samba or SSH **client** app (like [AndFTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftp&hl=en)) on Android device to pull files from PC.

You can do the same over air, too. Just connect PC & Android device in same Wi-Fi network & do the same. If you don't have Wi-Fi router, use [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) or [mHotspot](http://www.mhotspot.com/) (assuming its Windows PC) to make a virtual hotspot.